# Find tables where all columns in all rows are null

Tags: sql-server

I need to find the names of all tables where all columns of the table are `NULL` in every row.

I can get the tables that allow `NULL` values using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects A
WHERE TYPE = 'U'
AND NOT EXISTS
(   
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.all_columns B
    WHERE B.is_nullable = 0
    AND A.object_id = B.object_id
)
```

However I need to find tables where all rows and columns are `NULL`, one example is shown in the picture:

[image: Example table]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in a single statement, you'll have to cursor round the tables and generate dynamic SQL to check each in turn something like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #AllColumnsNullable (Name NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, NumRows INT, NumRowsAllNull INT);

DECLARE CT CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT name FROM sys.objects so WHERE so.type = 'U'
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.all_columns sc WHERE so.object_id=sc.object_id AND sc.is_nullable=0)
            ;
DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(MAX), @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
OPEN CT; FETCH NEXT FROM CT INTO @name;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN
    -- count rows
    SET @SQL = 'INSERT #AllColumnsNullable (Name, NumRows) SELECT '''+@name+''', COUNT(*) FROM ['+@name+'];';
    EXEC (@SQL);
    -- count rows all null
    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE #AllColumnsNullable SET NumRowsAllNull = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ['+@name+'] WHERE 1=1) WHERE name='''+@name+''';';
    DECLARE CC CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = (SELECT object_id FROM sys.objects WHERE name=@name);
    DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(MAX);
    OPEN CC; FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @col;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN
        SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, '1=1', '['+@col+'] IS NULL AND 1=1');
        FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @col;
    END;
    CLOSE CC;
    DEALLOCATE CC;
    EXEC (@SQL);
    -- done for this table
    FETCH NEXT FROM CT INTO @name;
END;
CLOSE CT;
DEALLOCATE CT;

SELECT * FROM #AllColumnsNullable;
DROP TABLE #AllColumnsNullable;
```

The first cursor is similar to your query, the only significant difference being it checks for "there are no columns that *aren't* nullable" instead of "there are some that are nullable" because if there is at least one not nullable column you can't have any rows with no non-NULL values (if you need to list tables with non-nullable columns but zero rows, as they have zero rows with non-null values, you need to make some changes to the above).

Within the loop through the cursor we use dynamic SQL to add the number of rows in the table to our temporary store, then the inner cursor puts more dynamic SQL together that adds to this the count of rows with no non-NULL values. Add `PRINT @SQL;` before `EXEC (@SQL);` to see what this produces for each table (or in place of the call to `EXEC` if you just want to see the code without running it).

This is going to take some time to run on tables with lots of rows as it will almost certainly do a table scan on each candidate table.

NOTE: a table containing all NULLs implies it has no primary key (as these have to be defined on columns that are not nullable) which suggests that you have a database design problem somewhere.

<sub>NOTE: if using SQL Server 2017 or later, you can replace the inner cursor constructing the dynamic SQL with a single query using `STRING_AGG()`. In fact for prior versions you can use the "normal" `FOR XML` hack to perform similar concatenation and avoid the inner cursor, though this would not improve clarity as much as simple `GROUP`ing and using `STRING_AGG()` would.</sub>

Comment: I'm reading from a phone with tiny screen so not sure how you did the 2nd query, per table. A suggestion: `select not exists (select * from tablename except select null, null, ..., null);`

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ: The two dynamically generated queries (the second constructed by the inner cursor) are made using the outputs of the outer cursor which returns the list of candidate tables. Looking at it after having slept there are much more concise ways to make the `UPDATE` query, not needing a nested cursor, I might revise the example when I have time as that'll make things clearer. I'm not sure about the use of `EXECPT`, wouldn't that return rows that *aren't* all NULL because the "all NULL" rows in the left hand are excluded by matching the all NULL row in the right?

Comment: @DavidSpillett Exactly. And the `not exists` will handle the rest. I made a small [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1147f/6), correcting my query (needs a `case` expression to handle the boolean output of `exists`. My point is that you need no counting this way and the `exists` subquery will exit with the first non-null row it will find. So, hopefully not doing  full scans for the big tables (unless they have all their rows with NULLs!)

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ, ah yes, I was only reading the inner part and missing the existence check. I think I agree that should be more efficient in some cases and never less efficient in others, I'll give it a try and update the answer when time permits.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through all tables and columns and tell you if a column only contains null values.

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#Temp_DBColumns') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp_DBColumns
Select b.name as columnName, a.name as TableName, c.name as SchemaName,
 CONCAT(c.name,'.',a.name) as LongName,
ROW_NUMBER()over(order by b.name,a.name) as Row#
into #Temp_DBColumns
from syscolumns b
    inner join sys.tables a on b.id = a.object_id
    inner join sys.schemas c on a.schema_id = c.schema_id



IF object_id('tempdb..#Temp_TableOne') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp_TableOne
Create table #Temp_TableOne (NULLVAL int
              ,ColumnName Varchar(250)
              ,TableName Varchar(250))



DECLARE 
@TableName Varchar(250),
@Count int,
@ColumnName Varchar(250),
@NULLVal NVARCHAR(max)

Declare @TableOne table 
              (NULLVAL int
              ,ColumnName Varchar(250)
              ,TableName Varchar(250))

set @Count =1

    WHILE @Count <=(Select count(*) from #Temp_TableOne)
    BEGIN

SET @TableName= (select a.LongName from #Temp_DBColumns a
                            where a.Row# = @Count)

SET @ColumnName= (select a.columnName from #Temp_DBColumns a
                        where a.Row# = @Count)

Set @NULLVal = 'insert into #Temp_TableOne
    SELECT COUNT(*) As ALLNulls, '''+@ColumnName+''' as ColumnName, '''+@TableName+''' as TableName
    FROM (SELECT TOP 1 1 AS note 
    FROM '+@TableName+' (nolock) where '+@ColumnName+' is not NULL) a' 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @NULLVal 

set @Count = @Count + 1

END


Select distinct a.columnName,a.LongName,b.TableName,b.ColumnName,b.NULLVAL from #Temp_DBColumns a
    left join #Temp_TableOne b on a.LongName = b.TableName and a.columnName = b.ColumnName
    where b.NULLVAL = 0 
    order by LongName
```